# I broke the FIND command of Ubuntu, mtime not working as it should

Tags: find

I'm building a script for backup and I'm heavily using the FIND with -mtime.
Yesterday I used find -mtime +1 a lot, to search the file modified more than a day ago.
At the end of the day, the command I used for the whole day stopped working.

```
user@ubuntu-4:~$ mkdir test
user@ubuntu-4:~$ cd test/
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ touch -t 201601180830 yesterdayMorning
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ touch -t 201601181725 yesterdayAfternoon
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ ll
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Jan 19 09:37 ./
drwx------ 9 user user 12288 Jan 19 09:36 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     0 Jan 18 17:25 yesterdayAfternoon
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     0 Jan 18 08:30 yesterdayMorning
```

The result of FIND -mtime n

```
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ find -mtime +1
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ find -mtime -1
.
./yesterdayAfternoon
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$ find -mtime 0
.
./yesterdayAfternoon
user@ubuntu-4:~/test$
```

I should be able to find the file named yesterdayMorning because at the time I'm writing (09:48 am of 19 january) that file is older than 1 day.

find -mtime -1 (or 0 too) show the correct result because the file's last modification is less than 24 hours.

And yesterday before 05.00 pm I swear it was working!

Comment: Have your tried the `-daystart` option?

Comment: No, only used -mtime for the whole day of yesterday. Probably too much.. and I ended up forgetting the exact mtime used for which case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not 24 hours ago but more than n days ago. I.e. for `-mtime +1` it would have to be modified two days ago.

Use find -mtime +0 to match also yesterday's files.

Comment: I tried this too but nothing.. The result is copied in the main question so you too can see
EDIT: my bad I created a file with wrong hours. Yes mtime +1 show file older than 2 days.   What??  I somehow managed yesterday to show file older than 24 hours with -mtime +1

Comment: -mtime +0 (mathematically incorrect) shows me what I want! I'm astonished .. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the accepted answer `-mtime +0` will work for you in this case.
Note:

```
find using -mtime and -daystart
-mtime n 
    File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.
-daystart 
    Measure  times  (for  -amin,  -atime,  -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and
    -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than  from  24  hours
    ago.
    This  option only affects tests which appear later on the
    command line.

date
Tue Jan 19 10:24:43 CET 2016
~/test $ ls -n
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Jan 18 10:15 yesterdayMorning10:15.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Jan 18 10:45 yesterdayMorning10:45.txt
~/test $ find -mtime +0
./yesterdayMorning10:15.txt

~/test $ find -mtime 0
./yesterdayMorning10:45.txt

~/test $ find -daystart -mtime +0
./yesterdayMorning10:15.txt
./yesterdayMorning10:45.txt
```

Comment: That's a good explanation! Haven't used the daystart but it seems I will to refine the script. Good job (: thank you!